# Oracle SQL Cumulative Sum with Identifying Column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and I am trying to combine two tables with Sums using a Union All, but I would like to identify the two returned rows as "LIVE" AND "ACTUALS".  My queries are structured like this...

```
select
SUM(JAN_2014) as JAN_14,
SUM(FEB_2014) AS FEB_14,
SUM(MAR_2014) AS MAR_14
from table A

union all

select
SUM(JAN_2014) as JAN_14,
SUM(FEB_2014) AS FEB_14,
SUM(MAR_2014) AS MAR_14
from table B
```

The output I would like would be....

```
DATA_VIEW  JAN_14  FEB_14  MAR_14
ACTUALS    10      15      20
LIVE       20      20      20
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What output are you currently getting w/ the sql that you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  'ACTUALS' AS DATA_VIEW,
        SUM(JAN_2014) as JAN_14,
        SUM(FEB_2014) AS FEB_14,
        SUM(MAR_2014) AS MAR_14
FROM tableA

UNION ALL

SELECT  'LIVE' AS DATA_VIEW,
        SUM(JAN_2014) AS JAN_14,
        SUM(FEB_2014) AS FEB_14,
        SUM(MAR_2014) AS MAR_14
FROM tableB
```